# ASP.NET Core Changing The Status in my properties model to warning, expired or Current by calculating the date and having it as a column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET Core, I have properties that are calculated based on other properties, for example, I have

public class Training
{

```
    public int TrainingID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Course Code")]
    public string CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Employee Id")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Initial Date")]
    public DateTime InitialDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = " Refrasher Date")]
    public DateTime RefrasherDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "InitialCertificate")]
    public string InitialCertificate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Refrasher Certificate")]
    public string RefrasherCertificate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Updated By")]
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    
    [Display(Name = "Training Status")]
    public string TrainingStatus { get; set; }


}
```

and TrainingStatus  is meant to be "Current " if (currentdate - RefrasherDate > 90days)  would be "Warning " if <=90 and >30 and "Expired" if <=30. the currentdate is not stored in the database but its todays date and TrainingStatus changes dynamically based on the calculated date.

Comment: Well, that is your model, basically the class that defines a new custom type that is going to be used as a database table. It should be defined under the `Models` directory.
You need to create some kind of auxiliary controller/class to make such verifications.

Answer (score 0):

One way is overriding  `DisplayStatus`'get  Like this:

```
 public string TrainingStatus
    {
        get
        {
            var totoalDays = (DateTime.Now - RefrasherDate).TotalDays;
            if (totoalDays > 90) return "Current";
            if (totoalDays <= 90 && totoalDays > 30) return "Warning";
            if (totoalDays < 30) return "Expired";


            return "";
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is your model, basically the class that defines a new custom type that is going to be used as a database table. It should be defined under the `Models` directory. You need to create some kind of auxiliary controller/class to make such verifications.

## Define the Controller

```cs
//Assuming Training is in the Models directory
using FolderName.Models;
using FolderName.DatabaseContext;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class TrainingController
{
    public static void ChangeStatus(DatabaseContext myContext)
    {
        //Query your database context to retrieve current information 
        //for Training class as a list
        List<Training> myTraining = myContext.Training.ToList();
        
        //Define TrainingStatus status
        foreach(var training in myTraining)
        {
             if((currentDate - training.RefrasherDate) > 90)
                 training.TrainingStatus = "Current";
     
             if((currentDate - training.RefrasherDate) <= 90)
                 training.TrainingStatus = "Warning";

             if((currentDate - training.RefrasherDate) <= 30)
                 training.TrainingStatus = "Expired";
        }
       
        myContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I wanted it to dynamically add the status values with out creating Event on database and also RefrashareDate is found on the property.